# question in JavaScript Uncaught type error ("" is not a function )

Tags: javascript, html, function

I want to change body color, font color and link color with functions in JS.

```js
function bodyBackgroundColor(color){
    var target = document.querySelector('body')
    target.style.backgroundColor=color
}

function bodyColor(color){
    var target = document.querySelector('body')
    target.style.color=color
}

function linkColor(color){
    var link = document.querySelectorAll('a')
    var i = 0
    while (i<link.length) {
        link[i].style.color=color
        i = i+1
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Night MOde Final</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="final_night.css">
    <script src="final_night.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        <a href="qwer">
            WEB
        </a>
    </h1>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <a href="asdf">
                HTML
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="zxcv">
                CSS
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="uiop">
                JavaScript
            </a>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <h2>
        Nightmode
    </h2>
    <p>
        Night mode making again...
    </p>

    <input type="button" value="NIGHT" onclick="
    if (this.value === 'NIGHT') {
    bodyBackgroundColor('black')
    bodyColor('powderblue')
    linkColor('powderblue')
    this.value='DAY'
    }
    else {
    bodyBackgroundColor('white')
    bodyColor('navy')
    linkColor('navy')
    this.value ='NIGHT'
    }
    ">
</body>
</html>
```

But I found that function linkColor is not working and details of error is that "linkColor is not a function".

I tried to check linkColor function with chrome console, and checked that just writing linkColor('red') or ('blue') is working well.

So I think error occurs when fuction linkColor is in if conditional statement in html document, but still I can't figure out what's wrong.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `onClick` needs to be passed a function. You're just assigning it a string which is what the error is telling you.

Comment: @Andy Are you talking about the `onclick` attribute on the `<input>`? No, the string is correct here. The error is about something different: `onclick` attributes create two implicit `with` scopes around the JS code inside them — one of which is scoped to `document` (the other one to the element itself). By calling `linkColor`, actually [`document.linkColor`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/linkColor) (a deprecated getter that returns an empty string) is “called” (which isn’t possible because strings aren’t functions).

Comment: Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [not recommended](/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead. **This is one of the many reasons why `onclick` should be avoided.**

Comment: It's weird. In an my time (25 years) of working with JS I've never seen anything like that. And you're right, but I'm leaving my comment up :). I've seen things like `<input onChange="myFunction()" />` obviously, and try to steer my junior devs away from inline JS and use modern methods, but that really _really_ caught me off-guard. @SebastianSimon. Sometimes the more knowledge you gain the more you lose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not recommended to inline JS. You should use `addEventListener` to add listener on HTML element.

But you can also get the button reference using [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to it

```js
function bodyBackgroundColor(color) {
  var target = document.querySelector('body')
  target.style.backgroundColor = color
}

function bodyColor(color) {
  var target = document.querySelector('body')
  target.style.color = color
}

function linkColor(color) {
  var link = document.querySelectorAll('a')
  var i = 0
  while (i < link.length) {
    link[i].style.color = color
    i = i + 1
  }
}


const button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (this.value === 'NIGHT') {
    bodyBackgroundColor('black')
    bodyColor('powderblue')
    linkColor('powderblue')
    this.value = 'DAY'
  } else {
    bodyBackgroundColor('white')
    bodyColor('navy')
    linkColor('navy')
    this.value = 'NIGHT'
  }

})
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>
    <a href="qwer">
          WEB
        </a>
  </h1>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <a href="asdf">
            HTML
          </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="zxcv">
            CSS
          </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="uiop">
            JavaScript
          </a>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <h2>
    Nightmode
  </h2>
  <p>
    Night mode making again...
  </p>

  <button type="button" value="NIGHT"> change theme</button>
```

Comment: `addEventListener` is definitely recommended and works, but the reason is wrong. The `onclick` attribute _does_ accept a string of JS code, _not_ a function.

Comment: @SebastianSimon If you write a JS functiona as a string then It will produce `Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name`

Comment: Function name should be passed to `onclick`.

Comment: There is no syntax error in the code as shown by the OP. I have no idea what you’re trying, but `onclick="if(){`…`} else{`…`}"` or `onclick="someFunction();"` are both definitely correct. You make it sound as if `onclick="someFunction"` was correct. Note that I’m talking about the _attribute_ (i.e. as in `<input onclick="someFunction();">`), not about the property (i.e. as in `someInput.onclick = someFunction;`); attribute values are always strings anyway. The reason for OP’s error message is explained in my comment under the question, and in more detail by the duplicate target.

Comment: @SebastianSimon You are right we can pass function as a string and pass the function name also. I apologize. Corrected mistake and learned something that I didn't know. Thanks ✌